# BeautifulSoup - "Couldn't find a tree builder" error, what am I missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Upon running my python script I am getting following error

```
 File "myfile.py", line 538, in parse_format_views_into_memsource_json
   page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'xml')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 246, in __init__
   % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

After reading a few posting about bs4, I changed the xml to lxml like below.

```
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Now I am getting the same error for lxml

```
 File "myfile.py", line 538, in parse_format_views_into_memsource_json
   page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 246, in __init__
   % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I am very puzzled about this situation.  I checked my pip list and surely I do have lxml.  The list below.

```
backports.functools-lru-cache (1.6.1)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.9.3)
certifi (2018.1.18)
chardet (3.0.4)
colorama (0.3.9)
distribute (0.6.19)
idna (2.6)
Jinja2 (2.10)
Logbook (1.2.1)
lxml (4.6.2)
Mako (1.0.7)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
Myghty (1.2)
mysql-connector (2.2.9)
p4python (2017.2.1615960)
Paste (2.0.3)
PasteDeploy (1.5.2)
PasteScript (2.0.2)
pip (9.0.1)
psutil (5.4.3)
psycopg2 (2.7.4)
pymssql (2.1.3)
pyodbc (4.0.22)
pypm (1.3.4)
pythonselect (1.3)
pywin32 (214)
PyYAML (3.12)
RBTools (1.0.4.dev1)
repoze.lru (0.7)
requests (2.18.4)
Routes (2.4.1)
setuptools (38.4.0)
six (1.11.0)
soupsieve (1.9.6)
SQLAlchemy (1.2.2)
texttable (1.4.0)
tqdm (4.19.5)
urllib3 (1.22)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Am I missing anything here?

==== Update ===

I have checked import on lxml.  Although I pip installed lxml, I cannot import lxml or lxml.etree.  What makes more confusing is that I can import bs4 without any problem.  I pip installed them at the same time and the same manner.  I don't know how to proceed from here.

I checked the pip package list again, this time from the script itself using following command.

```
import pkg_resources
print([p.project_name for p in pkg_resources.working_set])
```

It clearly shows that there lxml is available the the Python instance I am using.  Below is the output

> ['wsgiref', 'wheel', 'virtualenv', 'urllib3', 'tqdm', 'texttable',
> 'SQLAlchemy', 'soupsieve', 'six', 'setuptools', 'Routes', 'requests',
> 'repoze.lru', 'RBTools', 'PyYAML', 'pywin32', 'pythonselect', 'pypm',
> 'pyodbc', 'pymssql', 'psycopg2', 'psutil', 'pip', 'PasteScript',
> 'PasteDeploy', 'Paste', 'p4python', 'mysql-connector', 'Myghty',
> 'MarkupSafe', 'Mako', **'lxml'**, 'Logbook', 'Jinja2', 'idna',
> 'distribute', 'colorama', 'chardet', 'certifi', 'beautifulsoup4',
> 'backports.shutil-get-terminal-size', 'backports.functools-lru-cache']

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using python3? Are you running code in a virtualenv that doesn't have lxml?

Comment: Yes, I am working on a project written on 2.7 and it is not up to me to change the entire project.  It is not my choice.  I tried to voice my concern though.

Comment: @Kay. Make sure you can import `lxml` in python. It may be that your `pip list` is showing packages for another python interpreter. Make sure they align

Comment: @ M Z.  For some reason I cannot import lxml and lxml.etree.  It looks like lxml is installed judging from pkg_resources at the runtime.